# Using Selenium to get elements by class name, but I want to limit based on the online status of another class

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping pinnacle.com. Sometimes they have some offline bets and I want to adjust my web scraping to not include the title of the bet if the bet itself is offline. I am making a dataframe and I want the player name to be the index, but I can not do it as the selenium request gets title of the bets that are offline as well as the ones that are online, making the length of the index and data different. I want to be able to differentiate between the two but I am not sure how to do that.

This is my current code that gets all the elements in my list.

```py
driver.get("https://www.pinnacle.com/en/basketball/nba/brooklyn-nets-vs-charlotte-hornets/1564479365#player-props")

#retrieve name of player/type of bet
player_name_bet_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "style_titleText__35WhH")

#retrieve over name raw values
odds_name_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "style_label__2KJur", "market-btn style_button__34Zqv style_pill__1NXWo style_horizontal__10PLW style_disabled__2uBLz")

#retrieve over odds raw values
odds_values_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "style_price__15SlF")
```

I have tried an 'and not' statement but it returns a boolean, and I can't include that as the index. Please help.

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors                       https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php

Comment: How to know if a bet is offline?

Comment: There is another class that is created called title that has a whole other name. I would want to create a data frame with only the live bets and their titles